# Django post_save() signal triggered when an instance is deleted

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I'm currently working on a social network site with Django.

I am working on the "tag" feature, which sends a Notification to a user whenever they are tagged in a Post.

I created a post_save signal like this:

```
def post_tagged(*args, **kwargs):
  instance = kwargs['instance']
  message = f'{instance.user.slug} mentioned you in a post.'

  #Find in the content of the post if there are any "@username", if yes create a Notification object
  for user in MyUser.objects.all():
    if instance.content.find(f'@{user.slug}') != -1 and instance.user != user:
      Notification.objects.create(user = user, message = message)

models.signals.post_save.connect(post_tagged, sender = Post)
```

This is working fine when I create a new Post, but it also triggered when I delete a Post. This is the code in the view to delete a post:

```
if 'deletePost' in request.POST:
  postId = request.POST.get('deletePost', None)
  post = Post.objects.get(pk = postId)
  if request.user == post.user:
    post.delete()
    message = 'Success'
  else:
    message = 'Fail'
  jsonData = {"message": message,}
  return HttpResponse(json.dumps(jsonData))
```

Also if it helps you can see I'm using ajax to send the request to the view. And the delete is also working fine. The only problem is that it also create a Notification to the tagged users when I delete a post.

Anyone having the same issue? I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Please show us the whole view, not just the `if` condition.

Comment: @solarissmoke that particular view has >100 lines so I don't think it's a good idea. And I'm pretty sure that is the only part that interact with the Post model, others is irrelevant :)

Comment: Normally you shouldn't get a `post_save` signal when deleting a model, are you sure your Model isn't overriding the `delete` method to give it a different status (like 'deleted') rather than actually deleting it?

Comment: Also, @solarissmoke is right, other parts of your view might be saving the `post` instance. To be sure, set a breakpoint in your `post_tagged` method and check the call stack at that point so you know for sure this happens when calling `post.delete()` and not somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for helping guys :). I just found the problem. Turned out the problem was in another signal. I have a model call UserAction which has the foreign  key to the Post model. I have an action_deleted signal that deals with the Post when a UserAction instance is deleted. But I forgot to exclude the action called "CreatePost". So when the Post is deleted, the "CreatePost" action bind with it is also deleted -> which called the post.save() again. Managed to fix that and it works beautifully now :)

Comment: @dirkgroten my model is overrided by [django-safedelete](https://pypi.org/project/django-safedelete)

Comment: @alial-karaawi what's your point? if you use django-safedelete you're not actually deleting anything but just saving. Of course in that case your `post_save` signal will be triggered.